# Installing R 4.2.2 (ARM) fails

Tags: macos, install, r

I am trying to update from R 4.2.1 to R 4.2.2 via the .pkg installer. However, I can't install since I get the message `The installation failed. The installer encountered an error and let me contact the software manufacturer.` You can see a [similar case here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254559856). Seems like the only available solution so far is to reinstall macOS and I really want to avoid that. Anyone else having this problem? I also tried to trash the `R.app`, but it was of no use. I could also delete the `R.framework` folder, but I doubt it will be of any use. Any ideas here?

EDIT: I could succesfully install via commandline `$ sudo installer -pkg R-4.2.2-arm64.pkg -target /`. The same problem occurred trying to install XQuartz-2.8.5, which I could also succesfully install via CLI. Not all .pkg fail via GUI though. I could install Adobe Reader successfully via GUI.

`/var/log/install.log` show the same error for RStudio and XQuartz:

```
2023-03-02 14:12:13+01 [device] installd[802]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=110 "Beim Extrahieren von Dateien aus dem Paket „R-4.2.2-arm64.pkg“ ist ein Fehler aufgetreten." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Beim Extrahieren von Dateien aus dem Paket „R-4.2.2-arm64.pkg“ ist ein Fehler aufgetreten., NSURL=file:///Users/gernophil/Downloads/R-4.2.2-arm64.pkg#R-fw.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=org.R-project.arm64.R.fw.pkg, NSUnderlyingError=0x13c289e50 {Error Domain=PKXARArchiveErrorDomain Code=101 "archive open failed" UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/gernophil/Downloads/R-4.2.2-arm64.pkg, NSFileOwnerAccountID=501, NSFileHFSTypeCode=0, NSFileSystemFileNumber=33338670, NSFileExtensionHidden=false, NSFileSystemNumber=16777234, NSFileSize=90203062, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID=20, NSFileHFSCreatorCode=0, NSFileOwnerAccountName=gernophil, NSFilePosixPermissions=420, NSFileCreationDate=2023-03-02 13:01:34 +0000, NSFileType=NSFileTypeRegular, NSFileProtectionKey=NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName=staff, NSFileReferenceCount=1, NSFileModificationDate=2023-03-02 13:01:40 +0000, NSLocalizedDescription=archive open failed}}} {
        NSLocalizedDescription = "Beim Extrahieren von Dateien aus dem Paket \U201eR-4.2.2-arm64.pkg\U201c ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.";
        NSURL = "file:///Users/gernophil/Downloads/R-4.2.2-arm64.pkg#R-fw.pkg";
        NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=PKXARArchiveErrorDomain Code=101 \"archive open failed\" UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/gernophil/Downloads/R-4.2.2-arm64.pkg, NSFileOwnerAccountID=501, NSFileHFSTypeCode=0, NSFileSystemFileNumber=33338670, NSFileExtensionHidden=false, NSFileSystemNumber=16777234, NSFileSize=90203062, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID=20, NSFileHFSCreatorCode=0, NSFileOwnerAccountName=gernophil, NSFilePosixPermissions=420, NSFileCreationDate=2023-03-02 13:01:34 +0000, NSFileType=NSFileTypeRegular, NSFileProtectionKey=NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName=staff, NSFileReferenceCount=1, NSFileModificationDate=2023-03-02 13:01:40 +0000, NSLocalizedDescription=archive open failed}";
        PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "org.R-project.arm64.R.fw.pkg";
    }
2023-03-02 14:12:13+01 [device] installd[802]: PackageKit: Cleared responsibility for install from 9550.
2023-03-02 14:12:13+01 [device] installd[802]: PackageKit: Cleared permissions on Installer.app
2023-03-02 14:12:13+01 [device] installd[802]: PackageKit: Hosted team responsible for install has been cleared.
2023-03-02 14:12:13+01 [device] installd[802]: PackageKit: Running idle tasks
2023-03-02 14:12:13+01 [device] installd[802]: PackageKit: Done with sandbox removals
2023-03-02 14:12:13+01 [device] installd[802]: PackageKit: Removing client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=9550, uid=501 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer)
2023-03-02 14:12:13+01 [device] Installer[9550]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=110 "Beim Extrahieren von Dateien aus dem Paket „R-4.2.2-arm64.pkg“ ist ein Fehler aufgetreten." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6000018040f0 {Error Domain=PKXARArchiveErrorDomain Code=101 "archive open failed" UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/gernophil/Downloads/R-4.2.2-arm64.pkg, NSFileOwnerAccountID=501, NSFileHFSTypeCode=0, NSFileSystemFileNumber=33338670, NSFileExtensionHidden=false, NSFileSystemNumber=16777234, NSFileSize=90203062, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID=20, NSFileHFSCreatorCode=0, NSFileOwnerAccountName=gernophil, NSFilePosixPermissions=420, NSFileCreationDate=2023-03-02 13:01:34 +0000, NSFileType=NSFileTypeRegular, NSFileProtectionKey=NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication, NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName=staff, NSFileReferenceCount=1, NSFileModificationDate=2023-03-02 13:01:40 +0000, NSLocalizedDescription=archive open failed}}, NSURL=file:///Users/gernophil/Downloads/R-4.2.2-arm64.pkg#R-fw.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=org.R-project.arm64.R.fw.pkg, NSLocalizedDescription=Beim Extrahieren von Dateien aus dem Paket „R-4.2.2-arm64.pkg“ ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.}
2023-03-02 14:12:14+01 [device] Installer[9550]: Install failed: Die Installation ist aufgrund eines Fehlers fehlgeschlagen. Wende dich an den Hersteller der Software.
2023-03-02 14:12:14+01 [device] Installer[9550]: IFDInstallController 16DBF00 state = 8
2023-03-02 14:12:14+01 [device] Installer[9550]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.
2023-03-02 14:12:14+01 [device] Installer[9550]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'Die Installation ist aufgrund eines Fehlers fehlgeschlagen. Wende dich an den Hersteller der Software.'.
(sorry for German)
```

Comment: Did you contact the software provider as the error message indicates? What was their reply?

Comment: No I didn't. I didn't think this would be of any use. Anyway, I was able to install using `sudo installer -pkg R-4.2.2-arm64.pkg -target /`. Not sure, why the GUI doesn't work. I was also able to install other .pgk via the GUI.

Comment: Good to hear that you have successfully solved this. Would probably be useful to post it as an answer below.

Comment: I edited the question above since I still want to find out, why the GUI is not working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to give the installer [full disk access](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/install-with-pkg-file-failed.2367425/).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).